# Get last updated column from an update action in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

```
UPDATE sms.customerOtp
SET validateCounts = validateCounts + 1
WHERE customerID = '123'
```

After this update I need to run a select statement that should return the last updated value of `validateCounts`.

Is there any functions similar to `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to get the last updated value of a non-identity column?

Comment: You can use the `OUTPUT` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause:

```
UPDATE sms.customerOtp
    OUTPUT validateCounts
    SET validateCounts = validateCounts + 1
    WHERE customerID = 123;
```

Normally, I would put the result into a table variable, but you can use it without a table variable.